# Mapping data with 2 dimensional array with AXIOS and VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

I'm a beginner in `vuejs` and I'd like to map my data response in a two-dimensional table.

This is my data:

```
[{
  "origine": "",
  "nb": 15
}, {
  "origine": "?",
  "nb": 18
}, {
  "origine": "?L",
  "nb": 1
}, {
  "origine": "G",
  "nb": 298
}, {
  "origine": "I",
  "nb": 51
}, {
  "origine": "L",
  "nb": 1735
}, {
  "origine": "L?",
  "nb": 1
}, {
  "origine": "O",
  "nb": 4
}]
```

After mapping I want the data to be like this:

```
[
  ['', 15],
  ['?', 18],
  ['?L', 1],
  ['G', 298],
  ['I', 51],
  ['L', 1735],
  ['L?', 1],
  ['O', 4]
]
```

Or like this :

```
[
  '': 15,
  '?': 18,
  '?L': 1, 
  'G': 298, 
  'I': 51, 
  'L': 1735, 
  'L?': 1, 
  'O': 4
]
```

So far I've written this:

```
getResultcivitas(localisation) {
  axios
    .get('../api/civitasorigine/' + this.searchInputcivitas)
    .then(response => {this.origines = response.data.map (x => x.origine)})
}
```

I've find this but I don't know how to spell it out in my axios query.

```
map = origines.map(obj => {
  var rObj = {};
  rObj[obj.origine] = obj.nb;
  return rObj;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return an array from the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) functions' callback with `item.origine` and `item.nb`

```js
let data = [{
  "origine": "",
  "nb": 15
}, {
  "origine": "?",
  "nb": 18
}, {
  "origine": "?L",
  "nb": 1
}, {
  "origine": "G",
  "nb": 298
}, {
  "origine": "I",
  "nb": 51
}, {
  "origine": "L",
  "nb": 1735
}, {
  "origine": "L?",
  "nb": 1
}, {
  "origine": "O",
  "nb": 4
}]

let mappedData = data.map(item => {
  return [item.origine, item.nb];
})

console.log(mappedData)
```

Comment: I have formulated my second question about the objects in VueJs on this topic. Can you help me  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62531807/vuejs-how-to-build-an-object

Answer (score 2):

Well, you literally have all the answers, you just need to combine them:

```
axios
  .get('../api/civitasorigine/' + this.searchInputcivitas)
  .then(response => {
    this.origines = response.data.map(obj => {
      const rObj = {};
      rObj[obj.origine] = obj.nb;
      return rObj;
    })
  })
```