# Vuejs, how to build an object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, chart.js

Hello I'm trying to display graphics on my website from API, to display my graphic in column, I need to send him an object like this one

```
data: [{
            name: 'Data1',
            data: [
              ['ALIONIVS', 1],
              ['GARCIC(I)VS', 1],
              ['NONIVS', 1],
              ['SERVERS,A', 1]
            ],
          },
          {
            name: 'Data2',
            data: [
              ['TVTOR', 1],
              ['FVSCINVS', 1],
              ['GVTAMVS / GVMATIVS', 1],
              ['SEVERINVS, -A', 1],
              ['TVSCVS, -A / TVSGVS', 1],
              ['VEIENTA', 1],
            ]
          }
        ],
```

But I would like to have dynamic data
I'm retrieving data from my api with axios.

```
        axios
          .get('../api/civitasnomen/' + this.searchInputcivitas)
          .then(response => {
            this.data1 = response.data.map(item => {
              return [item.lemme, item.nb];
            })
          })

        axios
          .get('../api/civitascognomen/' + this.searchInputcivitas)
          .then(response => {
            this.data2 = response.data.map(item => {
              return [item.lemme, item.nb];
            })
          })
```

In my object I would like to retrieve both my api data

If write this in axios :

> axios
> .get('../api/civitasnomen/' + this.searchInputcivitas)
> .then(response => this.data1 = response.data )

For example Data1 =

```
[ { "nb": 1, "lemme": "ALIONIVS" }, { "nb": 1, "lemme": "GARIC(I)VS" }, { "nb": 1, "lemme": "NONIVS, -A" }, { "nb": 1, "lemme": "SEVERVS, -A" } ]
```

And Data2 =

```
[ { "nb": 1, "lemme": "TVTOR" }, { "nb": 1, "lemme": "FVSCINVS" }, { "nb": 1, "lemme": "GVTAMVS / GVMATIVS" }, { "nb": 1, "lemme": "SEVERINVS, -A" }, { "nb": 1, "lemme": "TVSCVS, -A / TVSGVS" }, { "nb": 1, "lemme": "VEIENTA" } ]
```

Comment: How does the data returned from the API look like ? i mean ` this.data = response.data` and ` this.data2 = response.data`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim data1 = [ { "nb": 1, "lemme": "ALIONIVS" }, { "nb": 1, "lemme": "GARIC(I)VS" }, { "nb": 1, "lemme": "NONIVS, -A" }, { "nb": 1, "lemme": "SEVERVS, -A" } ] 
and data2: [ { "nb": 1, "lemme": "TVTOR" }, { "nb": 1, "lemme": "FVSCINVS" }, { "nb": 1, "lemme": "GVTAMVS / GVMATIVS" }, { "nb": 1, "lemme": "SEVERINVS, -A" }, { "nb": 1, "lemme": "TVSCVS, -A / TVSGVS" }, { "nb": 1, "lemme": "VEIENTA" } ]

Comment: Your question is not clear and the data that your provide first doesn't have any common feature with that returned from api

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I want to make the data object dynamic. the data > name is fixe Data1 or Data2 but I want the data > data dynamic . I have change the data object to match with my api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you have `data` property initialized as an empty array:

```
data(){
  return {
   data: [],

  }
}
```

Then update it with result coming from API :

```
 axios
          .get('../api/civitasnomen/' + this.searchInputcivitas)
          .then(response => {
             this.data.push({
               name:'data1',
               data:response.data.map(item => {
              return [item.lemme, item.nb];
            })
            })
          })

        axios
          .get('../api/civitascognomen/' + this.searchInputcivitas)
          .then(response => {
             this.data.push({
               name:'data2',
               data:response.data.map(item => {
              return [item.lemme, item.nb];
            })
          })
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help you're helping me a lot, it's working perfectly. Thank you